# Why is vue-resize-directive not firing?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a .vue component file where I want to detect resizing of an element, and I'm having trouble getting [vue-resize-directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-resize-directive) wired up properly.

The element I'm testing is a table footer, but I've had the same result with a `div`. Here's the code from my template:

```
<tfoot><tr>
    <td :colspan="properties.length" v-resize="onResize"></td>
</tr></tfoot>
```

My script file includes:

```
var resize = require('vue-resize-directive');
module.exports = {
  directives: { resize },
  methods: {
    onResize: function() {
        console.log("resized");
    }
  }
}
```

The component compiles and renders properly, including the `div.resize-sensor` element that the directive adds, but resizing the table (or the entire window) doesn't result in any logging to the console or any warnings or errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: It has a number of dependencies (ResizeSensor.js and lodash). Are you including them all?

Comment: Is the `td` itself actually resizing?